# Form group error shown before the subscribe part is executed

Tags: angular

I am creating a form builder inside that (createForm()) but during update, the execution completes before the subscribe part works. So it throws the error message

> formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

But the form comes with the expected data.

```
if (output.action === 'create') {
  this.createForm();
} else if (output.action === 'update') {
  /* Get physician data from service */
  const physicianData = this.physervice.getPhysician(id);
  /* Subscribe to the service */
  physicianData.subscribe( res => {
    this.physicianData = res.body;
    this.createForm();
  });
}
```

**Create form is used to create the form builder.**

```
createForm() {
    this.rules = new Rules();
    this.physicianForm = this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl(((this.physicianData) ? 
        this.physicianData.name : ''), this.rules.name),
......
......
}
```

> Template Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="physicianForm">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="center-block">Name
    <input autocomplete="off" id="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name" value="" required>
  </label>

  <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="name?.errors['required']">
      Name is required.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="name?.errors['minlength']">
      Name must be at least 4 characters long.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="name?.errors['pattern']">
      Name must be alphabetic characters it should not include numbers or other characters
    </div>
  </div>
.............
.............
</div>
```

> Solution 1:I tried calling createForm() before if condition it works. But I hate calling it twice.

Is there any other options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your template code. i assume you don't have corresponding `[formGroup]="physicianForm"` in your template or vice versa, you might have it in template but your `createForm` doesn't run because of the condition.

Comment: I included template code as you requested, but template is fine also there is no condition in create form so far. The issue here is the execution delay in subscribe part.

Comment: Your physicianForm is undefined until the physicianData in the subscription is populated. As such, you're trying to bind to a value that doesn't exist in the template at the time the template is parsed.
Add an ```*ngIf="physicianData"``` to form will render form only when physicianData is ready.

Comment: nice. I think for me I need to add one more condition for create. Thanks.